# Jenkins Pipeline Utility steps plugin

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I installed pipeline utility plugin in my jenkins in windows system and tried using read properties command as below

```
        steps {

 script {
    def buildNumberProps = readProperties file: "(C:\\common\\\build.properties)"

}
        }
```

But, i am getting the below error **" C:\common\\build.properties does not exist, omitting from properties gathering"**

Request your help

Answer (score 0):

The `file` argument does not specify a valid file path. Try this instead:

```
def buildNumberProps = readProperties file: "C:\\common\\build.properties"
```